# SQL get unique records and Maintain the Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, distinct

I have records like below in my table.

[image]

I want distinct records and when I do group by it loses the order. I want to maintain the order. I want results like below:

[image]

This is my query:

```
select route_id,fixcode,fixdescription 
from route_fixcodes 
group by route_id,fixcode,fixdescription 
having route_id = 995063
```

Comment: You're missing the `order by` clause, just add that.

Comment: @DaleBurrell He want to keep show the rows as screenshot, dont use order by

Comment: I don't want the output to be ordered  in certain manner. I want my output which displayed in screenshot. the output is the data inserted from the .net side.

Comment: Your original data has no order to keep...

Comment: @Ryan Nghiem you understand correct.

Comment: The only way you can ensure its in the correct order, even if thats the order of insert, is to use an `order by` clause. And if you want it by the order of insert you either need an incrementing ID field or a date field to order by. The insert order means nothing.

Comment: Without an ORDER BY the result isn't ordered. Start with adding an ORDER BY clause to your original query!

Comment: how many distinct fixeddescription is there?

Comment: @Ketan Kota: I had displayed in status. there are displaying 3 duplicates.

Comment: there are 5 fixeddescription only ?

Comment: there is nothing like no solution. I got the solution. below is my query. select route_id,fixcode,fixdescription, MIN(id) as minid from route_fixcodes where route_id = @RouteId GROUP BY route_id,fixcode,fixdescription Order by minid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add distinct:

```
select distinct route_id,fixcode,fixdescription 
from route_fixcodes 
group by route_id,fixcode,fixdescription 
having route_id = 995063
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT _instead of_ GROUP BY seems fine, but the order will not be kept since it's no order...

Comment: but using group by will by default sort to columns used in group by which I don't want.

Comment: @jarlh. Maybe he has other records that need the GROUP BY.

Comment: @ut or : yes, correct. I have duplicate records which need to be group by but if I use group by it will default sort to group by columns which I don't want. The query should be like group by/distinct but maintain original sorting which is displaying in screenshot.

Comment: @kkakadiya you **CAN'T** maintain original sorting without an `order by` clause. There is no way. It is not possible. You have to specify the order!

Comment: @kkakadiya. What do you want to order by?

Comment: @ut or : I don't want to order by. just want to keep my original ordering.

Comment: @kkakadiya its the same thing - there **IS** no original ordering, there is a random ordering, which randomly in your case is the same as the insert order. But that is not guaranteed! You have to understand that without an `order by` clause in SQL Server - there is no known order - its random/undetermined. I don't think anyone is going to continue repeating this, you have the answer, you need an `order by` clause.

Comment: there is nothing like no solution. I got the solution. below is my query.            select route_id,fixcode,fixdescription, MIN(id) as minid from route_fixcodes where route_id = @RouteId GROUP BY route_id,fixcode,fixdescription Order by minid

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. I guess that's what you looking for

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[route_fixcodes](
    [route_id] [INT] NULL,
    [fixcode] [INT] NULL,
    [fixdescription] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO [route_fixcodes]
([route_id] ,[fixcode],[fixdescription])
VALUES
(995063,100,'Issue Observed'),
(995063,137,'Swap Altice One Pack'),
(995063,249,'Defective CPE Equip.'),
(995063,112,'Outside coax repair'),
(995063,258,'Preventative Maint'),
(995063,100,'Issue Observed'),
(995063,137,'Swap Altice One Pack'),
(995063,249,'Defective CPE Equip.'),
(995063,112,'Outside coax repair'),
(995063,258,'Preventative Maint'),
(995063,100,'Issue Observed'),
(995063,137,'Swap Altice One Pack'),
(995063,249,'Defective CPE Equip.'),
(995063,112,'Outside coax repair'),
(995063,258,'Preventative Maint')
GO


SELECT * INTO #route_seq FROM dbo.route_fixcodes


ALTER TABLE #route_seq ADD seq  [INT] IDENTITY(1,1)

SELECT MIN(seq) AS newseq,  route_id,fixcode,fixdescription 
FROM #route_seq
group by route_id,fixcode,fixdescription 
ORDER BY MIN(seq)
```

Comment: didn't this help?

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Let me assume there is one . . . I'll just call it `id`.  Then you can do:

```
select route_id, fixcode, fixdescription 
from route_fixcodes 
where route_id = 995063
group by route_id, fixcode, fixdescription 
order by min(id);
```

Note that I've changed the `having` clause to a `where` clause.  In general, this will reduce the the amount of data being aggregated -- and that is very good for performance.

If you have no ordering column, but specifically want the results in the order 100, 137, 249, 112, 258, then you can use a `case` expression or similar logic:

```
select route_id, fixcode, fixdescription 
from route_fixcodes 
where route_id = 995063
group by route_id, fixcode, fixdescription 
order by charindex(id, '100,137,249,112,258');
```

(This is just a convenient shorthand and will not work in all circumstances, but works for the data you provided.)

Comment: the below query gave me my desired result.                                                                                                                             select route_id,fixcode,fixdescription, MIN(id) as minid from route_fixcodes where route_id = @RouteId GROUP BY route_id,fixcode,fixdescription Order by minid

Answer (score 0):

the below query gave me my desired solution.

select route_id,fixcode,fixdescription, MIN(id) as minid from route_fixcodes where route_id = @RouteId GROUP BY route_id,fixcode,fixdescription Order by minid